# Laravel Eloquent, return rows where both conditions are True

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of Weeks that is joined to a property table, Weeks table looking like this:-

```
PropID, WeekDate,    Available

1     , 2015-07-04,      Yes

1     , 2015-07-11,      Yes

1     , 2015-07-18,      No

2     , 2015-07-04,      Yes

2     , 2015-07-11,      No

2     , 2015-07-18,      No
```

I want to select properties where both the weeks of the 4th and 11th are available. In the example above, I want to return two rows with PropID 1 as both are available and no rows from PropID 2 as only one of the weeks are available.

I've tried various ways, but either get nothing or always return the 1st, 2nd and 4th rows.

I think this is close, but it's still missing something as it is looking for dates that are <= AND >=

```
 $query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
            {
                $q->where(function($sub)
                {
                    $sub->where('WeekDate', '>=', '2015-07-04');
                    $sub->where('WeekDate', '<=', '2015-07-11');

                });
                $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
            })
                ->get();
```

Not sure this helps, but the Property table is simply

```
PropID, PropName

    1     , Property 1

    2     , Property 2
```

Just found that this SQL works.

SELECT PropID FROM tblweeks WHERE `WeekDate` IN ('2015-07-04', '2015-07-11') AND `Available` = 'yes' GROUP BY PropID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: Can you share your sample data of Property table? Wondering if that might  be helpful!

Comment: Can you post your model code.

Comment: Also assuming WeekDate is a Date, can you confirm that's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give your result as **Property 1** only:

```
$weeks = Property::whereHas('Week', function ($q) {
    $q->where(function ($sub) {
        $sub->whereIn('WeekDate', array('2015-07-04', '2015-07-11'));
        $sub->where('Available', '=', 'y');
    });
    $q->groupBy('property_id');
    $q->having('count(*)', '=', '2');
})->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, example table should have shown "Yes" and not "Y".

Comment: @PaulWright I've updated my answer as per your sql. I've regenerated data and code in my workstation and tested this. It gives Property 1 as result.

Comment: Genius. Many thanks Ariful and everyone else who helped on this.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe you do not need the second nested query.</strike>

```
$query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
{
  $q->where('WeekDate', '>=', '2015-07-04');
  $q->where('WeekDate', '<=', '2015-07-11');
  $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
})
->get();
```

**Updated**

Have you looked into [whereBetween](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses).

```
$query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
{
  $q->whereBetween('WeekDate', '2015-07-04', '2015-07-11');
  $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
})
->get();
```

Comment: This makes no difference at all (although you're correct, the nested where is useless)

Comment: No, Sorry, that just gives rows where Available = Yes and the date is either one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes i have did in your query :

Please check  this solution

```
$query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
{
  $q->where('WeekDate', '=', '2015-07-04');
  $q->orWhere('WeekDate', '=', '2015-07-11');
  $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
})
->get();
```

This should work and will return desire output

Comment: No, sorry this gives (`WeekDate` = '2015-07-04' or `WeekDate` = '2015-07-11' and `Available` = 'Yes').

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes, the query might be using group by query :

Please check this solution

```
$query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
{
  $q->where('WeekDate', '=', '2015-07-04');
  $q->orWhere('WeekDate', '=', '2015-07-11');
  $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
  $q->group('WeekDate');
})
->get();
```

This should work and will return desire output

Answer (score 0):

You actually need two `whereHas` for this:

```
 $query = Property::whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
                  {
                      $q->where('WeekDate', '>=', '2015-07-04');
                      $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
                  })
                  ->whereHas('Week', function($q) use ($arrive)
                  {
                      $q->where('WeekDate', '<=', '2015-07-11');
                      $q->where('Available', '=', 'Yes');
                  })
                  ->get();
```

Comment: No, sorry that isn't giving the correct result, getting everything with Available=Yes for those dates.

Comment: Only return the rows when they are available for BOTH dates. Thanks for all your help on this. Driving me crazy. I have updated the question now with SQL that works if that helps understanding.

Comment: Well that's actually what my code should be doing. Are you sure it doesn't work?